# How to use find and exec to execute multiple commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have such a need:
In the directory `video`, I need to

```
find ./video -type f | while read myfile; do
    tmp=`basename $myfile`   #example.mp4
    tmp="${tmp/.mp4/.html}"  #example.html
    cp index.html "$tmp"
    sed -i '' "s#sceneFilePath:.*#sceneFilePath: \"$myfile\",#g" $tmp
#done;
```

Here is my directory:

```
dir
 |--- video
 |     |--- example.mp4
 |--- index.html
 |--- generateHtml.sh
```

`generateHtml.sh` is just like above.
Here is what it does:
find the `example.mp4` file in `video`, then `cp index.html example.html` and change a string in the `example.html`.

It works well.

But now for some path and name of `.mp4` files, there are some special characters, such as `&`, , `-`. It doesn't seem that `while read` works for these cases.

I've heard that `find -exec` can handle all of special characters but I don't know how to use it for this case.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind

Comment: And run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ -- it's missing quotes, which is your largest immediate problem, not at all specific to `find`.

Comment: That said, if you're editing a JSON file, you should really use `jq` rather than hackery with `sed`. You're going to have a bad time here if any names need to be escaped or quoted to be valid inside your HTML file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) for detailed discussion.

```
find ./video -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' myfile; do
    tmp=$(basename "$myfile")   #example.mp4  -- consider also tmp=${myfile##*/}
    tmp="${tmp%.mp4}.html"      #example.html
    sed "s#sceneFilePath:.*#sceneFilePath: \"$myfile\",#g" \
      <index.html >"$tmp"
done
```

Note:

- `-print0` is used on the `find` end, and `IFS= read -r -d ''` is used on the `read` end; this ensures that all possible filenames (including names with newlines, including names with leading or trailing whitespace) are supported.
- The former substitution, which replaced the *first* instance of `.mp4` anywhere in the filename with `.html`, has been replaced with one which strips `.mp4` off the end of the filename, and appends `.html`.
- `"$myfile"` is quoted in invoking `basename`. This was your most substantial immediate bug in the original code, as previously a filename could be split into multiple separate arguments to `basename`.
- `$()` is used instead of backticks. This modern (and yes, POSIX-compliant) command substitution syntax can be easily nested and has much clearer semantics for backslash escapes within.
- `sed -i`, which is nonstandard and nonportable (the above was valid for MacOS but not for GNU), is unneeded here; one can skip the `cp` and do the transform in-line.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `bash` 4 or later, I wouldn't bother with `find` here; a `for` loop will be much simpler. Note there is no need to copy the file, then edit it in-place; just redirect the output of the `sed` command to the desired file.

```
for f in video/**/*.mp4; do
  [ -f "$f" ] || continue
  tmp=$(basename "$f" .mp4).html
  sed "s#sceneFilePath:.*#sceneFilePath: \"$f\",#g" index.html >  "$tmp"
done
```

If you don't actually need to recurse into subdirectories of `video`, you can simply use `for f in video/*.mp4; do`, and the whole thing works not just in earlier versions of `bash`, but environment where the shell and `sed` are both POSIX-compliant.